# Backing up on a second vps?

Tags: centos, backup

My hosting provider does not offer a free backup and I'm not going to pay for it.

I have 2 centos 5 64 bit vps, I'm working on 1 of them, I'm not using the 2nd one. I don't have a cpanel nor ftp.

I would like to know how to backup everything on the 2nd vps that I don't use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SCP or SFTP are your friends in this scenario.

The `scp` command works similarly to `cp`, but it copies files over an ssh connection.

`eli@oldserver:~$ scp -r /folder/with/important/stuff/ eli@123.123.123.123:/home/eli/stuff`

For more information and flags I refer you to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) of scp.

Your other option, SFTP is a protocol that is implemented in many file browsers. This approach will allow you to use a graphical interface.

- File browsers like Nautilus and Dolphin on desktop Linux distributions have this built in. Just use `sftp://eli@123.123.123.123` in the address bar.
- On Windows there is [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).
- For OSX there is [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/).

These SFTP tools will allow you to just drag and drop files on or off servers running ssh.

Comment: hey I ALWAYS use sftp, so i can use sftp to backup my files!!! thanks you!!!

Comment: hi sir I'm using winscp, would you tell me how to connect between 2 vps rather than a vps and a localhost?

Comment: This is not possible at the moment, as discussed in this WinSCP forum thread from 2004. http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=892

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all the data and config to the second server.  Testing whether your backup actually works is optional, but highly recommended.